# HTTPS Redirect in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, https, next.js

I'm trying to do a http to https redirect using next, 
so if the user enters the site at http://www.example.com redirect to https://www.example.com
I'm using GraphQL Yoga on the server side, so not sure how I could accomplish this in my index file on the server side.
I've tried using the meta tag and changing the protocol in the window object but no luck with doing so in server-side rendering.
Is there any way I can accomplish this redirect on the client side using next js or on the server side?

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
require('dotenv').config({path: '.env'})
const createServer = require('./createServer')
const db = require('./db')
const sslRedirect = require('heroku-ssl-redirect');
const server = createServer()
//Express middleware to handle cookies
server.express.use(cookieParser())
//decode JWT 
server.express.use((req, res, next) => {
    const { token } = req.cookies;
    if (token) {
      const { userId } = jwt.verify(token, process.env.APP_SECRET);
      req.userId = userId;
    }
    next()
})
//Populates user on request
server.express.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  if(!req.userId) return next()
  const user = await db.query.user({
    where: {id: req.userId}
  }, `{id, permissions, email, name}`)
  req.user = user
  next()
})
//start
server.start({
     cors: {
        credentials: true,
       origin: process.env.FRONTEND_URL
    },
}, starting => {
    console.log(`server is running on port ${starting.port}`)
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I have done in the past is started both a HTTP and a HTTPS server with express.
The HTTPS is the server with all the routes\API's configured. 
The HTTP server simply to redirects all GET requests to HTTPS. See the following code which could be used setup the HTTP server to do the redirect.

```
let httpRedirectServer = express();

// set up a route to redirect http to https
httpRedirectServer.get('*', (request, response) => {
    response.redirect('https://' + request.headers.host + request.url);
});

httpRedirectServer.listen(80);
httpRedirectServer.on('listening', () => {
    console.log("Listening to redirect http to https");
});
```

Alternatively on the client side a quick fix is to redirect in javascript by running something like.

```
// Check the URL starts with 'http://xxxxx' protocol, if it does then redirect to 'https://xxxxx' url of same resource
var httpTokens = /^http:\/\/(.*)$/.exec(window.location.href);
if(httpTokens) { 
    window.location.replace('https://' + httpTokens[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the client side redirect did the trick. For anyone wondering I installed a npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/global
And did as twomarktwo suggested for a client-side quick fix and added a check to make sure window has loaded.
I couldn't get the server side to redirect to https due to my server setup not using graphQL Yoga. 
import window from 'global'
```
    if(window.document) {
      let httpTokens = /^http:\/\/(.*)$/.exec(window.location.href);
      if(httpTokens) { 
        window.location.replace('https://' + httpTokens[1]);
      }
    }
```

Comment: I set up the client side solution as well but noticed that it takes a second for the app to redirect to https. Does the unsecure second pose a security threat?

Comment: @insivika although the "client side" solution is a nice quick hack to get it working server side redirect on any HTTP request to an HTTPS request is preferred.
The benefits are 1) You don't have that 'one-second' delay as the app loads in the browser and decides to redirect. The server will redirect the client immediately before sending the content.... security reason in next comment

Comment: 2) As far as security is concerned the client-side fix is not ideal. It still allows resources to be sent unsecured, and it's up to the client to execute the redirect script to request https resources. A client that does not have javascript enabled may end up browsing the entire site over HTTP. The server side redirect ensures the content from ALL requests on HTTP are not served, and the client should follow the redirect to the HTTPS location to retrieve that resource.

Comment: @twomarktwo how does the serve side solution get implemented when im not using a custom express server?

Comment: The client-side solution is UNSECURE! An attacker can modify the unecrypted code coming in and e.g. remove the SSL redirect